# C++ Вывод только положительного результата

Tags: c++, матрицы

Всем привет! Подскажите нужно создать матрицу такого вида:
4 - размер матрицы;

```
0 -1 -2 -3 
1 0 -1 -2 
2 1 0 -1 
3 2 1 0
```

Сверху то, что выводит код ниже, нужно чтобы все числа были положительным, т.е. так она должна выглядеть:

```
> '0 1 2 3 
   1 0 1 2 
   2 1 0 1 
   3 2 1 0`

    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m = 0, n = 0, l = 0;
    int size;
    int arr[m][n];
    cin >> size;
    for (m = 1; m <= size; m++) {
        for (n = 1; n <= size; n++) {
            if (m == n) {
                l = 0;
                arr[m][n] = l;
                cout << arr[m][n] << " ";
            }
            else {
                l = (m - n);
                if (l < 0) { l = -l; } 
                arr[m][n] = l;
                cout << arr[m][n] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Как это сделать ? Извиняюсь, что матрицы вывел, как код, иначе они в строку выглядели, чтобы удобнее было читать. Не знаю, можно ли так.

Comment: Что значит "чтобы все числа были положительными"? Например, вывести просто кучу единиц - это тоже "положительные". С таким ТЗ результат один - ХЗ...

Comment: Хотел добавить, что получается сделать с помощью добавления в else: if (l < 0) { l = -l; } . Но нужно как-то проще. Пока писал, ответ уже скинули.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int size = 4;
...
for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
    for (n = 0; n < size; n++) {
         cout << abs(arr[m][n]) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Получилось

Comment: С `INT_MIN` (т.е. числом **-2147483648**) `abs()`  не справится (как было INT_MIN так и останется). Правильное решение это сменить знак (все по правилам двоичной арифметики в дополнительном коде) перейдя в `unsigned`. Вот так `cout << (unsigned)(arr[m][n] ^ -1) + 1) << " ";` / Кстати, неправильный  вывод `INT_MIN` это типичная ошибка "ученических" реализаций печати целых чисел

Comment: @Igor, да совсем забыл

Answer (score 1):

Или так

```
if (arr[m][n]<0)
    arr[m][n]=-arr[m][n];
cout<< arr[m][n]<<" ";
```

Comment: Да, как раз такой метод использовал, но нужно было заменить его. Все-равно, Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: См. комментарий к ответу @Igor